# Representing $2n^2-1$ as a finite alternating sums on the Smarandache sequential sieve

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I write the positive numbers starting at $1$ in a triangle:$$\mathbb{N}_\triangle = \begin{matrix}
    &&&&&21&\ldots         \\
    &&&&15&20&\ldots       \\
    &&&10&14&19&\ldots     \\
    &&6&9&13&18&\ldots   \\
    &3&5&8&12&17&\ldots \\
    1&2&4&7&11&16&\ldots 
    \end{matrix}$$

I write $[n]$ for the $n^{th}-odd-column$ of $\mathbb{N}_\triangle$ and label the elements of $[n]$ as $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ where $x_1 =1+ {n(n-1) \above 1.5pt 2}$ and $x_n ={n(n+1) \above 1.5pt 2}$. For example $$[1] =\{1\}$$ $$[2] =\{4,5,6\}$$ $$[3] =\{11,12,13,14,15\}$$ Denote the number of elements in $[n]$ by $|[n]|$. I construct the following finite alternating sum for $[n]$  $$\mathfrak{a(n)} =x_n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{|[n]|-i}x_{|[n]|-i}$$ where $x_i \in [n]$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. I am asking if the following claim is true?

> If $n>1$ then $$\mathfrak{a(n)} =2n^2-1$$

For example consider $[3]$. First note that $|[3]|=5$ then

$$15+(-1)^{5-1}14+(-1)^{5-2}13+(-1)^{5-3}12+(-1)^{5-4}11=15+14-13+12-11=17$$ and $2*3^2-1=17$. The partition of the Natural numbers into the sets $[1],[2],[3],\ldots$ is known as  Smarandache's Sequential Sieve - [A007606](https://oeis.org/A007606).

***Edit 1***: I just noticed that $|[n]| =2n-1$ in which case we can actually write $$\mathfrak{a(n)} =x_n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{2n-1-i}x_{2n-1-i}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and this is pretty straightforward to see:

The largest element of $[n]$ (your $x_n$) is just the $(2n-1)$th triangular number $T_{2n-1}$.  Since $T_i=\frac12i(i+1)$, we have $x_n = T_{2n-1} = \frac12(2n-1)(2n)=n(2n-1)$.

The other $2n-2$ numbers in your alternating sum pair off into $n-1$ pairs of the form $(k+1)-k$, so each pair contributes a value of exactly $1$ to the sum; since there are $n-1$ pairs, the overall contribution from the terms other than $x_n$ is $n-1$.

Summing, then, the total overall value of your alternating sum is just $x_n+n-1 = n(2n-1)+n-1 = 2n^2-1$.